# Adding row and column in a multidimensional array if a new information is being added

Tags: c#

I got a multidimensional array that stores information about the name of the person to be met, the time and the date. Kind of scheduler.
How can i accept new details and store the new information by adding a new row and column.

Comment: So post some of your code show us what you got and where the issue is.

Comment: Forms? Web? Also, why not use a collection of `Meeting` classes? (Does it have to be an array?)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to replace the `Multidimensional Array` with a `Dictionary` ([see this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx))
Using `Dicitonary<K, V>` you will be able to add "new rows" (`KeyValuePairs<K, V>` ([see this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx)) to be precise), find, remove and modify. They are represented with a unique `Key` that will give you a value.
For example:

```
public class Program {
    public void Main() {
        Dictionary<int, Meeting> meetingDictionary 
             = new Dictionary<int, Meeting>(); //`int` on the left will be the key, and `Meeting` on the right is the value

            //int represents a unique Id of the meet event.
            //To add a new meeting:
            var date = new DateTime(2013, 7, 21); //date representor of the meet
            var meetingA = new Meeting("Obamba Blackinson", date); //object to hold this data.
            meetingDictionary.Add(1, meetingA); //note that Id can change to anything you wish, for example a string of the person's name.

            //How to pull it out of dictionary:
            var meetWithObamba = meetingDictionary[1];

            //**do w/e with the meet**. any modifications of meetWithObamba will edit the item in the dictionary too.
        }
    }

    public class Meeting {
        string PersonName;
        DateTime MeetingDate;

        public Meeting(string name, DateTime date) {
            PersonName = name;
            MeetingDate = date;
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you will, you can try working it around with a `List<V>` ([see this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)) which also can remove, add and modify items in a "bag" of specific type ''.
If you do not understand what the `<T>` means, see [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)